# Why am I seeing timezone strangeness in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

Using Python3, I do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
df = datetime(2018, 6, 1, hour=0, minute=0, tzinfo=timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(df)
2018-06-01 00:00:00-04:56
```

So, why does the date time get set to an offset of -4:56?  Shouldn't it be -5:00?  Why 4 minutes off?

Comment: This is why I use Arrow for everything time related.

Answer (score -1):

```
eastern_tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
eastern_time = eastern_tz.localize(datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0))
```

This gives you the correct result:

```
>>> print(eastern_time)
2018-06-01 00:00:00.000000-04:00
```

The reason is that python datetime module timezone objects are not directly compatible with pytz timezone objects. pytz documentation says:

> if you want to create local wallclock times you need to use the
>   localize() method documented in this document